# Is the phrase 'for me' wrong?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference, prepositional-phrases, style

Ever since I can remember, I've used '*to me*' and '*for me*' interchangeably.

Examples:

- > **To me**, writing about the future is too troublesome.
- > Writing about the future is too troublesome **for me**.

  Note: 'for me' sounds better when put at the end of the sentence. Re-arranging the phrase like that does not alter its meaning and purpose.

Now, does this make a difference? I'd once read somewhere that 'to me' is "right" and it's wrong the other way. I've seen many writers use 'for me', myself included.

Is it...

1. a myth like many well-known grammatical rules are

*or*

2. a fact which many people are not aware of?

Comment: Both of them are completely correct and gives the same meaning, in my opinion.

Comment: Read this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/expressing-an-opinion-to-me-or-for-me